# How to change Google Account language preferences? (NOT IN SETTINGS)

Tags: google-chrome, localization, google-account

I was in Korea several years ago; I do not speak Korean, but my Google Account language preferences have since been very strange.

I'm running into a problem where if I go to, say, https://www.google.com/chrome/, the page is displayed in Korean.

This solution is NOT in `chrome://settings/languages`. Here's a screenshot of what that looks like on my browser:

[image: img]

The solution is ALSO NOT in `https://myaccount.google.com/language`. Similar image as above.

Deleting `C:\Users\\[user]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data` fixes the issue when logged out, but logged in it reloads my preferences to include Korean, so the problem is clearly with my Google Account somewhere.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

> This solution is NOT in chrome://settings/languages

Have you tried adding Korean to the list of languages, then removing it?
https://crbug.com/784740

> Deleting C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data fixes the issue when logged out, but logged in it reloads my preferences to include Korean

Only if you sync everything from https://chrome.google.com/sync; choose what to sync and uncheck Settings.